# The Activity flag ScreenOrientation.Portrait does not exist

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin

I added the following code to the Activity flag and it says that it does not exist.

```
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

"ScreenOrientation.Portrait" is the only part that it says does not exist.  Do I have to add another reference? Do i have to define it somewhere else? Other forums just said to add the code above. Thank you to those that took the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following Activity flag you can force Portrait orientation for the activity:

```
[Activity (ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]          
public class YourActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change activity layout in code, use this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The activity's syntax in the **androidManifest.xml** actually looks like this:

```
 android:screenOrientation=[
          "unspecified" | "behind" |
          "landscape" | "portrait" |
          "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
          "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
          "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
          "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
          "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```

as it is described at android developers' manifest/activity element: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

To achieve this using xamaring (where you shouldn't edit your `androidManifest.xml`), you need to add a **custom attribute** to your class's declaration, to notify the compiler to generate the proper attributes for the `<activity .../>` tag:

```
[Activity (Label="MyActivityName", 
    ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MyActivity : Activity 
[...]
```